# ACPI errors preventing boot when using kernel version 5.*

Tags: kernel, boot, acpi

I have a Medion Akoya P6687 notebook, and I have started to use GNU/Linux in it a year and a half. I have always had problems with linux kernels, in fact only 4.19 version worked well for me. I have used other 4.x versions but they didn't work, but I'm not sure if it was because of ACPI errors.

I'm stuck with linux-4.19 kernel version because other recent versions (all of the 5.x kernel versions I have tested) give me the same ACPI errors when booting. This is specifically taken from Debian and `5.6.0-2-amd64` version but Arch gives the same results.

```
[   30.441861] APCI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECMD due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200110/psparse-529)
[   30.441872] APCI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.FNCL due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200110/psparse-529)
[   30.441879] APCI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.FN00._OFF due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200110/psparse-529)
[   30.441886] APCI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._REG due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200110/psparse-529)
[   31.696214] thermal thermal_zone1: critical temperature reached (128 C), shut
[   31.948073] thermal thermal_zone1: critical temperature reached (128 C), shut
[   61.971231] APCI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECMD due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200110/psparse-529)
[   61.971395] APCI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.FNCL due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200110/psparse-529)
[   61.971509] APCI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.FN00._ON due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200110/psparse-529)
... (similar messages appear every 30 seconds)
```

(posted and screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI3sU.jpg))

I have tested several distros (Arch, Debian and Void Linux) and the situation is the same: kernel 4.19 works (I currently use debian with 4.19 and I tried to boot an old arch .iso with that kernel and it boots with no problems), but recent kernel versions (5.x) don't, they have the problems above with the ACPI.

I can also add that, if I use the `acpi=off` flag, the notebook boots, but the battery and the touchpad are not detected, and in the most recent arch .iso the keyboard is not detected also.

I also have updated the BIOS to the last version but the errors persist, and I don't know what can I do to fix it.

If anyone can help me to find a solution I will be very grateful. Thanks.

And sorry if my english is not very good.

Comment: You might have to consider submitting a bug report somewhere (probably at bugzilla.kernel.org but only if using an unpatched kernel, not Debian's version). If it's non-reproducible without your kind of hardware, it becomes quite difficult to help here on SE. You'll probably be asked to do this https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/bug-bisect.html and I admit it can be a daunting task.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a nvidia graphic card, you should try blacklisting the nvidia modules, Add this to the boot parameters: `modprobe.blacklist="nouveau rivafb nvidiafb rivatv nvuvcvideo"`

Also add the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
blacklist nv
blacklist uvcvideo
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Medion's products are lousy, I have the same laptop.

To be able to use a "modern" kernel, including 5.x, you have to flash BIOS v.2.09. To do that you need to install Windows before! Once updated, you can use any kernel and everything works mostly fine.

The problem is that v.2.09 is no longer on their support site becauase it has a bug that if you enable CSM in the BIOS (boot up using the legacy way instead UEFI), the laptop get bricked forever, you have to send the laptop to Germany so they can replace the motherboard and they charge €250 unless it's under warranty. So they removed it from the web and now the last version listed is v.2.08, that can't boot any kernel newer that 4.19.

Those who make the BIOS in Medion are brilliant. They could already get a v2.10 that would solve all the problems, but they don't get that far. There is a thread about all this in the official Medion forum.

So you can search BIOS v.2.09 and flash it, but renember, never ever enable CSM support in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to boot using:

```
acpi_osi="!Windows 2015" acpi_osi="!Windows 2012" thermal.off=1
```

I have searched bios 2.09 but I cannot find it. If wish someone can upload it.